# Persisting Updated Objects in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, symfony-2.8

I have a symfony application where I am attempting to update an entity in the database using a setter.  However when I update the entity and call `$this->em->flush()` the entity is not persisted to the database.

Here is my service:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Exceptions\UserNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Class MyService
 * @package AppBundle\Service
 */
class MyService extends BaseService {

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * MyService constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * See if a user email exists
     * @param string $email
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkEmailExists($email){
        $this->user = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

        return !(is_null($this->user));
    }

    /**
     * add credit to a users account
     * @param User $user
     * @param integer $credit
     */
    public function addCredit(User $user, $credit){
        $user->addCredit($credit);

        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * add a credit to a users account
     * @param $email
     * @param $credit
     */
    public function addCreditByEmail($email, $credit){
        if(!($this->checkEmailExists($email))){
            throw new UserNotFoundException(sprintf('User with email %s not found.', $email));
        }
        $this->addCredit($this->user, $credit);
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Service;

use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\PurchaseFixture;
use AppBundle\Entity\Vendor;
use AppBundle\Repository\OfferRepository;
use AppBundle\Tests\TestCase;
use AppBundle\Entity\Offer;
use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\OfferFixture;
use AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\PaymentSystemFixture;

/**
 * Class UserOfferServiceTest
 * @package AppBundle\Tests\Service
 */
class MyServiceTest extends TestCase implements ServiceTestInterface
{


    function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        $this->setFixtures([
            'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\CityFixture',
            'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\CountryFixture',
            'AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\PaymentSystemFixture',
            'AppBundle\DAtaFixtures\ORM\UserFixture',

        ]);
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
    }

    /**
     * test the checkEmailExists() of app.vendor
     */
    public function testCheckEmailExists(){
        $myService = $this->getService();


        $this->assertTrue($myService->checkEmailExists('user1@user1.com'));
        $this->assertFalse($myService->checkEmailExists($this->fake()->safeEmail));
    }

    /**
     * test the addCredit functionality
     */
    public function testAddCredit(){
        $myService = $this->getService();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $this->assertEquals(0, $user->getCredit());

        $toAdd = $this->fake()->numberBetween(1, 500);
        $myService->addCredit($user, $toAdd);

        $this->assertEquals($toAdd, $user->getCredit());
    }

    /**
     * test the addCreditByEmail functionality
     */
    public function testAddCreditByEmail(){
        $myService = $this->getService();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $email = $this->getUser()->getEmail();

        $this->assertEquals(0, $user->getCredit());

        $toAdd = $this->fake()->numberBetween(1, 500);
        $myService->addCreditByEmail($email, $toAdd);

        $updatedUser =  $this->getEntityManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

        $this->assertEquals($toAdd, $updatedUser->getCredit());
    }


    /**
     * @return \AppBundle\Service\VendorService|object
     */
    public function getService(){
        $this->seedDatabase();
        $this->client = $this->createClient();

        return $this->client->getContainer()->get('app.admin_kiosk');
    }


}
```

The `testAddCredit()` test passes (because I'm checking the same object), but the `testAddCreditByEmail` fails with the following error: `1) AppBundle\Tests\Service\MyServiceTest::testAddCreditByEmail
Failed asserting that null matches expected 149.`

I've tried persisting the entity, flushing the entity (like: `$this->em->flush($user)`) all to no avail.  Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: Are your PHPUnit tests operating against a real database? Does the problem occur in "real usage" too, or could it be an aspect of how you're using Doctrine during the tests?

Comment: Yes, they're operating against a sqlite database @Darien.  I don't think so.

Comment: I'd first verify that `$this->getUser()` should always give you the same pre-existing User entity as the supposedly-equivalent `findOneBy(...)` call later on. If `$this->getUser()` is creating a new one, make sure you're doing a `->persist()` call before flushing. If there are multiple rows with the same email, `findOneBy()` may be returning the "wrong" one.

Comment: are you calling `$this->em->persist($this->user);` before calling `$this->em->flush()`?

Comment: I agree with @Confidence... you have to persist then flush.

Comment: @Confidence @ehymel Email is a unique key, and if I call `$this->em->persist($user)` I get this: `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO`.... `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email_canonical`

Comment: then you probably have to find your user by Email, before you update it. and your entity defitintion might have some flaws. Make sure the `email` field is defined as a unique key. Check the doctrine documentation or the symfony examples for that

Comment: @Confidence isn't that what I do when I set `$this->user`?

Comment: And I would flush the table after each test. in the `tearDown`method, this is necassry for keeping the states on each unit test clear. consider using mocking instead of real databases, as recommended earlier.

Comment: I new database is spun up for every test @Confidence

Comment: checkEmailExists is poorly named considering that it also saves user as a property.  Very unexpected side effect.  Consider renaming to findUseByEmail and then returning user or null as appropriate.  I think that will make things a bit easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: @JakeSylvestre If it's truly a new, fresh, *empty* database... Then what's the uniqueness constraint stopping you from inserting the new user?

Comment: @Darien the fixture produces the user I'm updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

In the test case I just had to refresh the entity by doing `$this->getEntityManager()->refresh($user)` (on the original $user entity).  Thanks!